# Widget Kit Broken on brand new installation

Tags: joomla-3.x, widgetkit

Google Console Error

TypeError: Cannot read property '_widget' of undefined

angular-63423c4c.js:102

Cannot Save Changes, change images or text!

Comment: at Object.d.editContent (wk-scripts-180d9ef6.js:9)
    at wk-scripts-180d9ef6.js:9
    at angular-63423c4c.js:265
    at angular-63423c4c.js:112
    at n.$eval (angular-63423c4c.js:126)
    at n.$digest (angular-63423c4c.js:123)
    at n.$apply (angular-63423c4c.js:127)
    at l (angular-63423c4c.js:81)
    at F (angular-63423c4c.js:85)
    at XMLHttpRequest.C.onload (angular-63423c4c.js:86)

Comment: Update to the latest version (if you haven't already), clear your browser cache and retry.

Comment: Done all of this using incognito and still no results :(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed add always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 to php.ini

Comment: Well... who would say that recommended PHP 5.6 might have a bug with setting 'always_populate_raw_post_data = 0'... Thanx for a tip!